# Using local server as a part of CDN

Tags: cdn, local-system

I would like to use CDN for my website. But more than 70% of the requests would be from within my own network. so I am planning to use my local server as part of the CDN, so that when somebody from within the network visits my website, the static content is delivered from my local network/server and when somebody from outside accesses the website, then an appropriate server from CDN is used.

What are the CDNs that can support a set-up like this. Can I do this with Amazon Cloud Front.

Comment: Why would the CDN need to be aware that your internal DNS is rerouting the traffic?

Answer (score 0):

The CDN you use does not matter. On your internal network, you simply add DNS entries for the CDN pointing to your local server which will act as CDN.

That way, when local users visit your site, the CDN host resolves to your local server and voila.

Comment: Sounds feasible. Let me check that and get back to you.